# Update AssignedTo on workitem using REST

Tags: rest, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I want to update the AssignedTo field on the workitem in TFS 2015. I tried the below request but it doesn't work. Can anyone guide with it?

```
[
          {
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/fields/System.Title",
            "value": "Child work item"
          },
            {
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/fields/System.AssignedTo",
            "value": "Leo Dsouza <dsouzaleo@hotmail.com>"
          },
          {
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/fields/System.Description",
            "value": "Description goes here"
          }
        ]
```

Comment: Did you get any returned information?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks well. More ways and details to use [Rest API for work item](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/wit/work-items) from MSDN.

I was wondering if it was caused by some other things such as permissions. Please try to assign this workitem to the user Leo Dsouza in TFS GUI.

Comment: Thank you for confirming.. I just realized the error is related to angle brackets. I just need to escape them in XML..

Comment: I wound up only using email address as the value and omit the angle brackets all together.